# Adding a Web Service for ReportExecution2005 - Resource cannot be found C#

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I'm trying to add the ReportExecution2005 Web Service into my project to allow me to execute reports from within my program.

We do this in other programs that are written in VB.net however, these programs have a namespace added for ReportingService that's around 3000 lines of code as the company has always struggled with adding the ReportExecution web service. Before I begin converting this code from VB.net to C# I thought I'd try again in getting it working the proper way.

I'm currently going to the Add Web Reference page, and putting the following:

```
http://reportserver/Reports/ReportExecution2005.asmx
```

This is returning a 404 error saying the resource can't be found. I've checked the URL over and over and got colleagues too. So I'm not really sure what else the issue could be.

[image]

Is there something that needs adding onto our report server for me to be able to add the web reference?

If anyone has had this issue before how did you solve it?

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: If you try the following URL in your browser you should get an XML response

`http://Your_SSRS_ServerNameHere/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx?wsdl`

This is not my area of expertise but if this fails then you should investigate that first.

Comment: Omg you absolute legend! The issue was that I was putting /Reports as I thought that's what the name of our report server was. But I just need to put /ReportServe

Comment: /Reports is the web portal/normal user interface /Reportserver is the service address. Glad you got it sorted...